# Reload Ajax/Javascripts afer .html() data load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a page that loads the data into the page through the following ajax function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){             
                function loadData(page){                  
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "inc/load_data.php",
                        data: "p="+page+"XXXXXXXXXXX",
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            //alert(msg);
                            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            { 
                                $("#container").html(msg);
                                //**MODIFIED CODE
                                $(document).delegate('a.vote_up','click', f_vote_up);   
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
  });
```

//Loaded Message

```
$msg.='<span class="vote_buttons" id="vote_buttons'.$row['id'].'">
       <a href="javascript:;" class="vote_up" id="'.$row['id'].'"></a>
       <a href="javascript:;" class="vote_down" id="'.$row['id'].'"></a>
    </span>';
```

The message that is loaded has some links that need to work with a another Ajax function(given below), which is apparently not working. The second function(below) is loaded before the data is loaded into the page. I suspect, may be since this function is loaded way before the data is loaded, the second function is not recognizing the click on vote_up. Is there any way to fix it??? I'm not too familiar with AJAX, I would really appreciate some help.. Thank you

```
$(function(){
    $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
    //get the id
    alert("Hi");
        //REST OF THE CODE
}
```

//***NEW FUNCTION

```
function f_vote_up(){
    //get the id
    the_id = $(this).attr('id');

    //REST OF THE CODE
    $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).html("Hello, Testing Response!");
    alert("End of Func!"); // <
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call that second function, it's only grabbing all the `a.vote_up` elements that *currently exist on the page*. When you add more links to the page later on, they don't know to listen for the click.

You can do one of two things to fix this:

1. Add the click listener to each new link when you add it to the DOM. But this is a bit of work, because you'd have to change how your AJAX function builds the links, and you'd have to turn that click-listener-assigning function into something standalone that you could use at any time.
2. Instead of doing using the `click` method, use the `delegate` method instead:

   ```
   $(document).delegate('a.vote_up', 'click', function () { ... });
   ```

[More info on event delegation with jQuery.](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery)

Comment: way more elegant than my answer.. +1

Comment: Thanks for the direction. So I modified the code to rebind(deligate) the listener(I have modified the code above with the new changes. ). It seems to be working. But, the problem is, when i make changes to one of the elements that was loaded through the first function, the change is reset back when it exists the function. For example the "Hello, Testing Response" does not stay on the span when it exits the f_vote_up function.

Comment: @Gokul Can you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something that shows the problem?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc
Hey JSFiddle is not really working for me, I'm trying to simplify  my code for that. In the mean time, let me put the problem in this way.

If you look at my last delegate function "f_vote_up", it is loading "Hello, Testing Response" text into the "vote_buttons" span element. But this text disappears after the alert("End of Func!"); and it's showing the original contents of "vote_buttons"(which is from "$msg.=" above)

I'm sorry if its really confusing, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey it's ok, i figured out. It was that $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) causing the problem. Now its working fine. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

you should bind your click event after you load the html

```
   $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "inc/load_data.php",
                            data: "p="+page+"XXXXXXXXXXX",
                            success: function(msg)
                            {
                                //alert(msg);
                                $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                { 
                                    $("#container").html(msg);
                                       $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
                                      //get the id
                                       alert("Hi");
                                       //REST OF THE CODE
                                         });
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `live` function to bind an event to dynamically created elements, i.e.:

```
$("a.vote_up").live('click', function(){
        //get the id
        alert("Hi");

    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

This will effectively bind this click event to all elements which match the a.vote_up selector, now and in the future.